# How to implement fallback for idempotent KafkaProducer?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am currently implementing a fallback mechanism for `KafkaProducer` where in, if the `KafkaProducer.send()` fails due to some reason (for example, like the metadata fetch timeout) and the record gets expired after the delivery timeout, the records still should exist in some persistent backup so that I can resend them later.

Here I will be taking the records from a file and then pushing them to Kafka and once they are acknowledged they will be removed from the file.

If for some reason the `KafkaProducer` goes down and is restarted, it will check for the entries in the file and then call `KafkaProducer.send()` on each item in the order and then proceed sending the subsequent items.

This mechanism is required because, the producer here is not a consumer, nor is it backed by a database, this applies when there is a flow of data from some source like a TCP or UDP channel.

> What happens if the KafkaProducer has sent a message and it is
>   persisted to Kafka broker but before the acknowledgement is received
>   by the producer the producer is killed? *Does it not duplicate if it is sent again after the restart?*

Going, through the idempotent producer, I see that there is usage of producer PID, but does the same PID gets reused on restart?

**How does Kafka uniquely identify a producer despite of its restarts?**
If it does not, how to implement a fallback mechanism with idempotence?

Answer (score 1):

> What happens if the KafkaProducer has sent a message and it is
>   persisted to Kafka broker but before the acknowledgement is received
>   by the producer the producer is killed? Does it not duplicate if it is
>   sent again after the restart?

If it is a non-transactional producer, if the process is killed before the acknowledgement from Kafka and after the message is persisted, then you will end up with duplicates.

Since you remove from the file only after acknowledgement and your process died before acknowledgement, it will resend all those that are there in the file during the next start.

In order to avoid duplicates, here is a workaround.

1. Get the [last message from Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57726845/2534090) and get its timestamp.
2. Delete all the records in the file until that timestamp (because they are actually *sent*. Only you did not get acknowledgment, so they are still in your file).
3. Send all the records *after* (greater than) that timestamp.

For this, you need to:

1. Put the timestamp yourself while producing i.e. in the `producer.send()` itself and you must also maintain it in the file.
2. When you are putting timestamp, ensure that your timestamp is accurate enough for your load (though it is uncommon to have more than one record processed in a millisecond *typically*, sometimes you would nevertheless want to use `System.currentTimeMillis()+counter`)

> P.S: This works good if you have a single producer.

On the other hand, if you have multiple producers, you may need to have a `producer.id` for each producer in the header itself along with its timestamp and you may need to filter out the last message produced by a producer with the given `producer.id`.

For this you may need consume (poll) all the messages since the last acked offset of the producer.

Answer (score 0):

identifying the "same" producer across restarts requires that you provide the `transactional.id` producer config (which is not a default behaviour).

you would also need to set `enable.idempotence` and have at least 3 brokers. for more details on the configs see https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs and for more background on how this works see https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/

Comment: that means we have to commit the transaction on acknowledgment?

Comment: from reading it appears everything you produce would need to be under a transaction (which you would need to periodically commit. the shorter the period the lower the latency cost, but the higher the total overhead). 
I personally dont bother with kafka transactions much as they are slow and rather limited. If, instead, you put UUIDs on records you produce and de-dup on the consumer side and/or make sure side effects are idempotent your overall performance will be better and your latency lower.

Comment: UUID idea seems to be good and I wonder why this is not implemented in the KafkaProducer for idempotence (probably they could have added a header with the UUID and then do the de-duplication on the broker side itself)!

Comment: kafka producer idempotence is implemented with either ints or longs - which are cheaper than UUIDs. however, this only "guards" the socket between a producer and a broker. 
UUIDs on records, in combination with some Cache<UUID> on the consumer side will filter-out UUIDs you've seen. this is generally more powerful (protects against both producer and consumer issues) but requires (potentially) a lot of memory.