# Is there a way to get the last message from Kafka topic?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a Kafka topic with multiple partitions and I wonder if there is a way in Java to fetch the last message for the topic. I don't care for the partitions I just want to get the latest message.

I have tried `@KafkaListener` but it fetches the message only when the topic is updated. If there is nothing published after the application is opened nothing is returned.

Maybe the listener is not the right approach to the problem at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This following snippet worked for me. You may try this. Explanation in the comments.

```
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topic));

        consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(10));

        consumer.assignment().forEach(System.out::println);

        AtomicLong maxTimestamp = new AtomicLong();
        AtomicReference<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> latestRecord = new AtomicReference<>();

        // get the last offsets for each partition
        consumer.endOffsets(consumer.assignment()).forEach((topicPartition, offset) -> {
            System.out.println("offset: "+offset);

            // seek to the last offset of each partition
            consumer.seek(topicPartition, (offset==0) ? offset:offset - 1);

            // poll to get the last record in each partition
            consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(10)).forEach(record -> {

                // the latest record in the 'topic' is the one with the highest timestamp
                if (record.timestamp() > maxTimestamp.get()) {
                    maxTimestamp.set(record.timestamp());
                    latestRecord.set(record);
                }
            });
        });
        System.out.println(latestRecord.get());
```

Comment: Looks like there is a problem... even when the offset is 0 your code still tries to substract 1 in consumer.seek(topicPartition, offset - 1);

Comment: What happens if the network is slow or Kafka is busy? Then the poll(10 seconds) might return zero records or a partial result.

Comment: @WernerDaehn it has to be adjusted according to the network condition, may be it can be made configurable, that is an example snippet.

Comment: @JavaTechnical Yes, understood. But per my knowledge there is no good solution. You have to wait for a long time and hope it was long enough. What "long" means, depends on the use case. There is a Jira item for that where I have added some comments. Would appreciate if others comment as well. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-10009

Comment: consumer.poll() should not be in the foreach loop. This way you poll as many times as the number of partitions. We should first seek to end -1 for each partition and then poll only once.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to consume the latest message from each partition and then do a comparison on the client side (using the timestamp on the message, if it contains it). The reason for this is that Kafka does not guarantee inter-partition ordering. Inside a partition, you can be sure that the message with the largest offset is the latest message pushed to it.